# Converting text in image to labels in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.0

I have map like the below image and I want convert numbers to labels automatically.

Is there any method to do this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. While the ArcScan extension can capture linework, hand-written text is the most difficult data to extract from images. If you find another tool to do this extraction, make sure it captures the pixel coordinate from which it was extracted. Note that ArcGIS 10.0 has been retired for a number of years; while I doubt much text processing has been introduced in the six, nearly seven, major releases since then, using decade-old software is not going to be an advantage.

Comment: I also recommend looking into scanning.  The Texas Digital Newspaper program documents the [software](https://library.unt.edu/digital-projects-unit/software/#ocr-software) they use.  The GIS software presents the newspapers as if they were maps note the `lat` and `lon` in this url: https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth293967/m1/1/zoom/?q=kuykendall&resolution=2&lat=3371.0999755859375&lon=3271.1000366210938

Comment: It is almost impossible to extract the numbers automatically. I agree with Vince, even if you have ArcScan extension, it will not extract the hand written numbers. In fact the image has poor quality, you cannot differentiate between 6 and 1 in some numbers, and zeros are almost disappeared. The quickest way is to enter the numbers manually.

Comment: "Manually" can include a simple toolbar to increment values by an interval and ease the data entry aspect, but the human computer is much better at this task than supercomputers (which is why [CAPTCHA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) often involves "enter text" requests)